# Create new jQuery ui tab and populate with Ajax data

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabs

I've got a set of jQuery ui tabs that starts with one tab which is pre-poluated with data from another page. That works fine. What I am trying to do is create a series of links that when clicked will dynamically add a new tab, and load the new tab panel with the data in the link path. Here's the code:

```
$(function(){
var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({
    add: function(event, ui) {
        $tabs.tabs('select', '#' + ui.panel.id);
    }
});
$('.add-tab').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var tabName=$(this).text(),
        tabNumber=-1;
    $tabs.find('ul li a').each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).text() == tabName) {
            tabNumber = i;
        }
    });
    if (tabNumber>=0)
        $tabs.tabs("select",tabNumber)
    else
        $tabs.tabs("add",this.href , tabName )
    return false
})
})

<a href="../views/subscribers.htm" class="add-tab">Subscribers</a>

<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="../views/dashboard.htm">Dashboard</a></li>  
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
</div>
</div>
```

So when you click the "Subscribers" link, it should add a new tab with the title "Subscribers", and load the data from "subscribers.htm" into the tab panel. Everything looks correct, so I'm not sure what's wrong here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery UI Tabs Add method is deprecated: http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-add-and-remove-methods-and-events-use-refresh-method.

Click the button below to see working code.

```js
$(function() {
  var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();

  $('.add-tab').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var tabName = $(this).text(),
      tabNumber = -1,
      tabLink = $(this).attr('href');
    $tabs.find('ul li a').each(function(i) {
      if ($(this).text() == tabName) {
        tabNumber = i;
      }
    });
    if (tabNumber >= 0)
      $tabs.tabs("select", tabNumber)
    else {
      $("<li><a href='" + tabLink + "'>" + tabName + "</a></li>")
        .appendTo("#tabs ul");
      $("#tabs").tabs("refresh");
    }

    return false
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css">
<a href="../views/subscribers.htm" class="add-tab">Subscribers</a>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="../views/dashboard.htm">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, that almost works. It adds the new tab with the correct title, but the content isn't loaded into the new tab. You can see here:

http://bushidodesigns.net/avst/examples/tabs.html

Note: I altered your script slightly so it targets "tab-menu" rather than #tabs ul because it was getting messed up when the content had list items in it.

Comment: Actually your code works fine.  If you check the JS console when you click the new Subscribers tab, you'll see a 404 error because the page '/remote/tab.html' doesn't exist.  I replaced that page in the console to a valid page, refreshed the jquery tabs, and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, but re-read the original question. I said that when you click the link, it needs to load whatever href is in the link you clicked on. I can't hardcode the link in the script because I need to have multiple links on the page. For example:

    <a href="about.htm" class="add-tab">About</a>
    <a href="contact.htm" class="add-tab">Contact</a>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to manishie for solving the first piece of the puzzle. I figured out the second, so here is the complete answer. You need to capture the href and store it as a var like so. Then it works perfectly. I'm surprised they don't have an example of this on the jQuery UI site:

```
$(function() {
var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();
$('.add-tab').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault()
var tabName = $(this).text(),
tabLink = $(this).attr('href'),
  tabNumber = -1;
$tabs.find('.tab-menu li a').each(function(i) {
  if ($(this).text() == tabName) {
    tabNumber = i;
  }
});
if (tabNumber >= 0)
  $tabs.tabs("select", tabNumber)
else {
  $("<li><a href=" + tabLink + ">" + tabName + "</a></li>")
    .appendTo(".tab-menu");
  $("#tabs").tabs("refresh");
}
return false
})
})
```